# Referencing UserForm public variable in vba

Tags: vba, ms-office

There is a userform with the following code:

**UserFormA**

```vb
Public BdayResult As Birthdays

Private Sub cbOk_Click()
    Dim frm As UserFormBirthdays
    Set frm = cbOk.Parent
    frm.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Debug.Print "Initialize"
    Dim frm As UserFormBirthdays
    Dim sEmployeesExcelFilePath As String
    sEmployeesExcelFilePath = "C:\Users\arun_jayapal\Documents\Employees.xlsx"
    Debug.Print (sEmployeesExcelFilePath)
    
    Set frm = lblRunDate.Parent
    
    
    lblRunDate.Caption = frm.BdayResult.RunDate
    '...other code stripped for brevity
End Sub
```

In some other routine I am initializing an instance of that form and calling `Show()`

```vb
'inside some sub
Dim frm as new UserFormA

set frm.BDayResult = b 'some object reference

frm.Show vbModal
```

Code enters the UserForm_Initalize routine. It proceeds to execute the line `lblRunDate.Caption = frm.BdayResult.RunDate`. I get an exception saying:

```
Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set
```

And the debugger indicates line in the sub, i.e. `set frm.BDayResult = b`

Hoping someone can point where I messed up.

Comment: Why do you use `frm.BdayResult.RunDate`? `BdayResult.RunDate` is sufficient, and if you really want to qualify it, use `Me.BdayResult.RunDate`. You don't need the variable `frm` (I guess the idea is to get the form object, but you can use `Me` instead)